# sdk-11.1.0.7.0-linux-x86_64/instantclient_11_1/sdk/include/nzerror.h:115:11: fatal error: oratypes.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, oracle, ubuntu, oracle-call-interface

I am trying to connect oracle 11g express on my Windows 10 installed by C++ program writing in Linux Ubuntu 18.4 LTS. I set path of include to includes file given by Oracle. I set path of Directories to given shared libraries by oracle. I just set namespace `oracle::occi`. The main method still empty I just build project but getting error

> ./../../Desktop/oracle OCI/sdk-11.1.0.7.0-linux-x86_64/instantclient_11_1/sdk/include/nzerror.h:115:11: fatal error: oratypes.h: No such file or directory.

I am using Netbeans on Ubuntu for coding of C++; I want to connect Oracle database on Windows 10 over the network by just change localhost to IP.

One more thing, I created a project in Visual Studio 2019 import all library for Windows it work but fetch one record and exception caught at some thing like Myproxy Error function.

Visual Studio problem later but I want it on Linux first.

```
#include <cstdlib.h>

using namespace std;

using namespace oracle::occi;

void main(){

}
```

I just do this and set the paths which I explained.

Comment: Do you have that file? What have you done to solve either of your issues? Also, please write clear descriptions & what you have done.  That definitely improves your chances of getting help.

Comment: #include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
using namespace oracle::occi;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    

    return 0;
}

Comment: Please don't add code to comments. There is an [edit] link under your question.

Comment: @JamesZ please check